# Hardhat Errors: Invalid value null supplied to : QUANTITY

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing, unittesting, mocha

Getting this error some times while testing a Hardhat file.
But when I cancel that script and **run that same script** again, it works.

The complete error is here:

```
    "before each" hook: Before Each for "mint Batch":
     InvalidResponseError: Invalid JSON-RPC response's result.

Errors: Invalid value null supplied to : QUANTITY
```

[image]

Comment: Pasting the code snippet would help.

Comment: I commented out the forking url that I had pasted in the Hardhat.config.ts file. The test cases run easily.

Looks like the mainnet rpc url used in forking was not working at times.